# Unable to install Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running: 
Mac OSX 10.6.8
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0] and
rubygems-1.8.9

But when I type in `sudo gem install rails`

I get the following errors:

> ERROR:  Error installing rails: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
>   extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use an open source pre-packaged Rails stack, like [RubyStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack)  (disclaimer, I am one of the developers). It is basically an all-in-one installer package, so there is nothing to compile / install (it can as easily be removed)

Answer (score 1):

I think the rails-dev* libraries are missing. So, you can just install the "rails-dev*" libraries on your system and try again to install the rails gem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the system ruby?

I suggest you:

1. Install [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/)
2. Install Ruby 1.9.2 using rvm
3. Install Ruby on Rails 3.1

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should check the log files that it pushes errors to, but it's more than likely that various gcc libraries are missing. [Re]Install XCode and try again.